# How to engage different function on different select

Tags: javascript, html, null, switch-statement

That's my second script ever. I'm learning basics at the same time. I would like to engage different function on different option selected.

I try to give value to different option to use it later where the switch is.
It says cannot set property of null. If someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong it would be amazing. Please forgive me for silly mistakes, 3 days of learning in total, unfortunately theory doesn't work on me if i will not try it.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2> Daily calorie intake</h2>
    <input type = "number" placeholder = "your height" id = "height" min = "1" max = "230"><p></p>
    <input type = "number" placeholder = "your age" id = "age" min = "1" max = "120"><p></p>
    <input type = "number" placeholder = "your weight" id = "weight" min = "1" max = "500"><p></p>
  Your sex
    <select name = "sex" id = "sex">
      <option value = "1" id = "male">male</option>
      <option value = "2" id = "female">female</select><p></p>
      <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    </div>

  <script>
    var height = document.getElementById('height').onclick;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').onclick;
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').onclick;
    var sex = 1;

    function calculate(height, age, weight, sex) { 
      switch(sex) {
        case sex: 1
          calculate = 66.5 * (13.75 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.76 * age)
        case sex: 2
          calculate = 655.1 * (9.56 * weight) + (1.85 * height) - (4.68 * age)
          break;
        default: 1
      } 
      document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML = calculate
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` means that the object that you are calling `.innerHTML` on doesn't exist. In your case that's this line:

```
document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML = calculate
```

and you get that error because you don't have an element with an `id` of `calculate`. If you don't have that element, you can't call `.innerHTML` on it.

You also need to get the data out of your form fields with the `.value` property, not the `onclick` property.

See additional comments below:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample Page</title>
  <style>
    div { margin:1em; } /* adds vertical space before and after each div */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- You can't have an <h2> if you don't already have an <h1> for it to be 
         a sub-section of. Don't use HTML elements because of how they style the output.
         Use CSS to style. Also, don't use <p></p> to create vertical space. Again, use 
         CSS for style. -->
    <h1> Daily calorie intake</h1>
    <div><input type="number" placeholder="your height" id="height" min="1" max="230"></div>
    <div><input type="number" placeholder="your age" id="age" min="1" max="120"></div>
    <div><input type="number" placeholder="your weight" id="weight" min="1" max="500"></div>
    <div>Your sex
      <select id="sex">
        <option value="1" id="male">male</option>
        <option value="2" id="female">female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button>Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    // Do your event binding in JavaScript, not in HTML
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", calculate);
    
    // Get references to the elements you'll need (not the value of their onclick properties)
    var height = document.getElementById('height');
    var age = document.getElementById('age');
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
    
    var sex = 1;

    // You don't need any arguments because you already have references to the fields
    // where the data is.
    function calculate() { 
      // Declare the variable the will hold the result and don't use the
      // name of the function as the name of the variable
      let result = null;
      
      switch(sex) {
        // To get the data out of a form field, you must access its .value property
        case sex: 1
          result = 66.5 * (13.75 * weight.value) + (5 * height.value) - (6.76 * age.value);
          break;
        case sex: 2
          result = 655.1 * (9.56 * weight.value) + (1.85 * height.value) - (4.68 * age.value);
          break;
        default: 1
      } 
      
      // Make sure you reference elements that exist and don't use 
      // .innerHTML when there is no HTML in the string. 
      document.getElementById('output').textContent = result;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, this code is working

```js
  var height = document.getElementById('height');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  var boton = document.getElementById('boton');

function calculate(height, age, weight, sex) {
  switch(sex) {
    case 1:
    var calculo = 66.5 * (13.75 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.76 * age);
    break;
    case 2:
    var calculo = 655.1 * (9.56 * weight) + (1.85 * height) - (4.68 * age);
    break;
    default: 1
    }
  console.log(calculo);
  return calculo; 
}

boton.addEventListener('click', () => calculate(height.value, age.value, weight.value, 1));
```

```html
<button id="boton"> Click me </button>
<input type = "number" placeholder = "your height" id = "height" min = "1" max = "230"/>
<input type = "number" placeholder = "your age" id = "age" min = "1" max = "120"/>
<input type = "number" placeholder = "your weight" id = "weight" min = "1" max = "500"/>
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow should be more than just posted code that works. It should explain what the problem was and how your solution solves it. Additionally, you've removed the `select` from the code, which was the entire point of the question.

Comment: Hello, thank you for all help. I tried to use code with Event but notching happens on button click. Is it supposed to show option box after the click? Today I will be studying Event, but what if I would like to keep button under height, weight, age plus keep selection?

Comment: I would love to have the most simple example of 2 values added by the user used in a different way in a function to generate differents scores depend on user choice

Comment: @Pawel, try hit F12 key to enter dev mode on browser, result will logged through the console. But you can put result as text, just add another `<div id="result"></div>` and at `return` line of `calculate` function put `document.getElementById("result").innerText = calculo;`